# Remove tab from TabBarController with different users iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

[image: Login to TabBarController]

As you seen in the picture above, there're one login screen, tab bar will appear after login successfully.
What I want to do is, let say there are two different user such as Admin and Staff, they have different login credentials, the Admin login will show all the tab at the bottom, however, the Staff login can just see the first tab. How could I do that? Any idea or code example to refer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In login screen you can override prepareForSegue as shown below

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let destinationTabBar = segue.destinationViewController as? UITabBarController {
           if (!isAdmin) {
               destinationTabBar.viewControllers?.removeAtIndex(adminScreenIndex)
           }
        }
    }
```

In the code above, you check if the user is admin in prepareForSegue method for tab bar controller. If the user is not admin, you remove needed screen (by `adminScreenIndex` index)

Comment: I did it by your way, thank you! Such an easy way from you compare to the resources that I found from others website.